# Does "submitted to Thomson Reuters" mean that a publication will actually be indexed?

Tags: conference, indexing

I have seen a few conferences that state on the call for submissions that the conference will be "submitted for indexing in Thomson Reuters Conference Proceedings Citation Index (ISI Web of Science)."

Does submission mean they will 'apply' and could be rejected, or are all submissions accepted?

Comment: It sounds like an attempt at making the conference appear more reputable than it is.

Answer (score 3):

It does sound like rather tentative wording.

Thomson Reuters cannot, would not, and should not accept all and any submissions of anything for indexing - it would swamp the system with spam.

So to me, it sounds like the conference has applied to be indexed, but it is certainly ***not*** absolutely guaranteed that they will be included in the Thomson Reuters Conference Proceedings Citation Index.

Answer (score 3):

It only means that was it **submitted**. In order to be added to the TRCP index, the submission needs to **approved** by the Thomson Reuters staff before it will be added. If the information on the conference website is up to date it means they have not (yet) been rejected but that does not mean their submission or application will be approved. I have no idea how long the wait for approval is.

In the best case, this is a signal that a conference's reputation is not yet firmly established. Even if it is eventually accepted, submitting to a conference with no real reputation is a risky choice.